# Run-time error '713' when trying to open report (activereport) from vb6 exe application

Tags: dll, vb6, windows-xp, activereports

When I run my application (based on VB6 with ActiveReport 2.0 ) that already installed on computer win xp , I got an error message when I open the report menu (that should be shown some activereport). That error is refer to dll for active report, but I couldnt see any problem with that since I already put arpro2.dll on it. Does windows XP doesnt support ActiveReport? or maybe there is another problem? because I Run it in other computer, it work fine

Comment: Would you, please, provide a piece of code ilustrating what you are trying to achieve and narrow the question as much as possible (otherwise it is going to be closed).

Comment: probably dlls and OCX components are not registered on the machine, simple adding of dll to the folder with application can't help here. please try to use regsvr32 tool, e.g. regsvr32 [filepath]/exclexpt.dll

Comment: I Already add the library with regsvr32 but it failed, I assumed that this happen because of the version of windows XP or maybe its service pack

Comment: then it requires another component registered before or you need to use regsvr32 as administrator. the most simple way to be sure that issue relates to the components registration is to install ActiveReports on the same machine with "as Administrator" option.